# mysqli query fails, no errors

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a database, called 'catalog', and a table, called 'categories'. The table has 3 columns in this order: categoryId, categoryName, parentCategory. I'm trying to grab categoryId and categoryName for each row that has a parentCategory = 'root'. I thought it was a straightforward query, but I'm apparently doing something wrong, because I keep getting the message--Couldn't execute query--but no mysql error is being displayed. I've posted my code below. Can anyone point me straight?

P.S. I do have values assigned to the $db variables; I just didn't include those here.

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_password,$db_database)
    or die ("Couldn't connect to server: ".mysqli_error());

function display_children($parent) {
    $query = "SELECT categoryId, categoryName FROM `categories` WHERE parentCategory=".$parent;
    $result = mysqli_query($connect,$query)
        or die ("Couldn't execute query: ".mysqli_error());

    echo "<ul>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          echo "<li>".$row['categoryName']."</li>";
          display_children($row['categoryId']); 
    }
    echo "</ul>";
    mysqli_close($connect);
}

?>

<div class="menu">    
<?php
    /* Menu Write */
    display_children("root");
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Please, if you're using `mysqli`, which is a good thing, use **SQL placeholders**. What you're doing here is extremely dangerous. Your query should contain `WHERE parentCategory=?` and you should make a call to [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to associate the placeholder value.

Comment: @tadman - I will look into the placeholders. Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: It shouldn't be a big deal, you're just one line away from making it work that way. If you use them in a disciplined fashion, you're almost entirely unlikely to introduce a damaging [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/php).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The display_children() function doesn't have access to the $connect variable.

Try this:

```
function display_children($parent) {
    global $connect;
    $query = "SELECT categoryId, categoryName FROM `categories` WHERE parentCategory=".$parent;
    $result = mysqli_query($connect,$query)
        or die ("Couldn't execute query: ".mysqli_error());

    echo "<ul>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          echo "<li>".$row['categoryName']."</li>";
          display_children($row['categoryId']); 
    }
    echo "</ul>";
    mysqli_close($connect);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_error()` needs the link with the database as parameter.

So the code for the error looks like this then:

```
or die ("error: " +mysqli_error($connect));
```

This is also described here:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Mayby this helps with the error reporting...

Comment: I tried adding the $connect variable into the mysqli_error(), but it didn't change anything. There were still no errors reported.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you just need to quote the value of `$parent` in your query.

```
$query = "SELECT categoryId, categoryName FROM `categories` 
          WHERE parentCategory = '" . $parent . "'";
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: What you suggested above does work in combination with KayakJim's answer above. But I also discovered that the concatenation isn't necessary for the query to work. Just solid single quotes around the variable inside the double quotes of the query. Thanks for the feedback though!